# Python error, " 'module' object has no attribute 'lstrip' "

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

Python documentation from http://docs.python.org/library/string.html :

> `string.lstrip(s[, chars])`
>
> Return a copy of the string with leading characters removed. If *chars* is omitted or `None`, whitespace characters are removed. If given and not `None`, *chars* must be a string; the characters in the string will be stripped from the beginning of the string this method is called on."

```
Python 3.1.2 (r312:79360M, Mar 24 2010, 01:33:18) 
[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5493)] on darwin
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> import string
>>> x = 'Hi'
>>> string.lstrip(x,1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    string.lstrip(x,1)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'lstrip'
>>>
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: it should give you TypeError as 1 is not char.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Documentation for py3k version is located here: http://docs.python.org/py3k/index.html

`string` functions were removed in py3k and you have to use now [`str` methods](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/stdtypes.html#str.lstrip):

```
>>> x = 'Hi'
>>> x.lstrip('H')
'i'
```

Note, that as documentation says, `chars` **must** be a string. Not an integer.

Comment: and string module is deprecated since python 2.5

Comment: @Ant: string module is just fine, it's only some function were deprecated.

Answer (score 4):

For Python 2.6 the following works ...

```
import string
x = u'Hi' #needs to be unicode
string.lstrip(x,'H') #second argument needs to be char
```

For Python 3.0 the previous solution won't work since `string.lstrip` was deprecated in 2.4 and removed in 3.0.

Another way is to do:

```
"Hi".lstrip('H')  #strip a specific char
```

or

```
" Hi".lstrip() #white space needs no input param
```

Which I think is the common widely use of it.

**Edit**

To add deprecation of `string.lstrip` in Python 3.0 - thanks for the comments on this answer that mentioned it.

Comment: Also, `string.lstrip` is not the right way of doing it, as it has been deprecated in Python 3

Comment: Do you mean the fact that I mention Python 2.6 ? or the first block of code ?

Comment: Right I did not know it was deprecated in 3.0 I'll mention that - thanks.

Comment: it wasn't **not** deprecated in py3k. it was deprecated in 2.4, in py3k these function simply don't exist.

Comment: @SilentGhost: That is right, I meant they don't exist at all (I can't seem to edit my comment though)

Answer (score 1):

You don't look the good doc you are using python 3.1 the right doc is here http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/string.html

Comment: not me, but probably because the URL that you gave leads to the `string` module, not to the `str` methods that he needs to read about.

Answer (score 1):

This was changed for Python 3.x.

The method you referring to is only available for string instances, not the module `string`. So you don't need to import anything:

```
 assert 'a ' == '  a '.lstrip()
```

Comment: It was changed in **2.x** so that you didn't need to import anything.

Answer (score 1):

You have found the Python 2.7.1 version of the docs (look at the top left corner of the screen). `string` functions were deprecated in Python 2.x in favour of `str` and `unicode` methods, and removed totally in Python 3.x. See the 3.x docs [here](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods).