# Package install error, “ 'module' object has no attribute 'lstrip' ”

Tags: python, package, python-3.5, qutip

I had a problem installing package `qutip` in windows 10.

```
Installing without the fortran mcsolver.
Compiling qutip\cy\sparse_utils.pyx because it changed.
Compiling qutip\cy\graph_utils.pyx because it changed.
[1/2] Cythonizing qutip\cy\graph_utils.pyx
[2/2] Cythonizing qutip\cy\sparse_utils.pyx
Compiling qutip\control\cy_grape.pyx because it changed.
[1/1] Cythonizing qutip\control\cy_grape.pyx
running install
running build
running config_cc
unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
running config_fc
unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
running build_src
build_src
building py_modules sources
creating build
creating build\src.win32-3.5
creating build\src.win32-3.5\qutip
building extension "qutip.cy.spmatfuncs" sources
building extension "qutip.cy.stochastic" sources
building extension "qutip.cy.sparse_utils" sources
building extension "qutip.cy.graph_utils" sources
building extension "qutip.control.cy_grape" sources
building data_files sources
build_src: building npy-pkg config files
running build_py
creating build\lib.win32-3.5
creating build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip
copying qutip\about.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip
copying qutip\bloch.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip
copying qutip\bloch3d.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip
copying qutip\bloch_redfield.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip
copying qutip\continuous_variables.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip
copying qutip\correlation.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip
copying qutip\countstat.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip
copying qutip\distributions.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip
copying qutip\entropy.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip
copying qutip\eseries.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip
copying qutip\essolve.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip
copying qutip\expect.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip
copying qutip\fileio.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip
copying qutip\floquet.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip
copying qutip\graph.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip
copying qutip\hardware_info.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip
copying qutip\ipynbtools.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip
copying qutip\logging.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip
copying qutip\matplotlib_utilities.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip
copying qutip\mcsolve.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip
copying qutip\mesolve.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip
copying qutip\metrics.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip
copying qutip\operators.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip
copying qutip\orbital.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip
copying qutip\parallel.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip
copying qutip\partial_transpose.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip
copying qutip\permute.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip
copying qutip\picloud.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip
copying qutip\propagator.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip
copying qutip\ptrace.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip
copying qutip\qobj.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip
copying qutip\random_objects.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip
copying qutip\rhs_generate.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip
copying qutip\sesolve.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip
copying qutip\settings.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip
copying qutip\setup.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip
copying qutip\simdiag.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip
copying qutip\solver.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip
copying qutip\sparse.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip
copying qutip\states.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip
copying qutip\steadystate.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip
copying qutip\stochastic.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip
copying qutip\subsystem_apply.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip
copying qutip\superoperator.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip
copying qutip\superop_reps.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip
copying qutip\tensor.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip
copying qutip\testing.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip
copying qutip\three_level_atom.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip
copying qutip\tomography.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip
copying qutip\utilities.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip
copying qutip\version.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip
copying qutip\visualization.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip
copying qutip\wigner.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip
copying qutip\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip
copying build\src.win32-3.5\qutip\__config__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip
creating build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip\ui
copying qutip/ui\progressbar.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip/ui
copying qutip/ui\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip/ui
creating build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip\cy
copying qutip/cy\codegen.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip/cy
copying qutip/cy\setup.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip/cy
copying qutip/cy\utilities.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip/cy
copying qutip/cy\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip/cy
creating build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip\qip
copying qutip/qip\circuit.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip/qip
copying qutip/qip\circuit_latex.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip/qip
copying qutip/qip\gates.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip/qip
copying qutip/qip\qubits.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip/qip
copying qutip/qip\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip/qip
creating build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip\qip\models
copying qutip/qip/models\circuitprocessor.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip/qip/models
copying qutip/qip/models\cqed.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip/qip/models
copying qutip/qip/models\spinchain.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip/qip/models
copying qutip/qip/models\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip/qip/models
creating build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip\qip\algorithms
copying qutip/qip/algorithms\qft.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip/qip/algorithms
copying qutip/qip/algorithms\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip/qip/algorithms
creating build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip\control
copying qutip/control\dynamics.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip/control
copying qutip/control\errors.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip/control
copying qutip/control\fidcomp.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip/control
copying qutip/control\grape.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip/control
copying qutip/control\loadparams.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip/control
copying qutip/control\optimconfig.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip/control
copying qutip/control\optimizer.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip/control
copying qutip/control\optimresult.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip/control
copying qutip/control\propcomp.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip/control
copying qutip/control\pulsegen.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip/control
copying qutip/control\pulseoptim.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip/control
copying qutip/control\setup.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip/control
copying qutip/control\stats.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip/control
copying qutip/control\symplectic.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip/control
copying qutip/control\termcond.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip/control
copying qutip/control\tslotcomp.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip/control
copying qutip/control\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip/control
creating build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip\tests
copying qutip/tests\test_basis_transformation.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip/tests
copying qutip/tests\test_brmesolve.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip/tests
copying qutip/tests\test_correlation.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip/tests
copying qutip/tests\test_countstat.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip/tests
copying qutip/tests\test_cqed.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip/tests
copying qutip/tests\test_eigenstates.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip/tests
copying qutip/tests\test_enr_state_operator.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip/tests
copying qutip/tests\test_entropy.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip/tests
copying qutip/tests\test_expect.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip/tests
copying qutip/tests\test_fileio.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip/tests
copying qutip/tests\test_floquet.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip/tests
copying qutip/tests\test_gates.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip/tests
copying qutip/tests\test_graph.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip/tests
copying qutip/tests\test_mcsolve.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip/tests
copying qutip/tests\test_mcsolve_f90.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip/tests
copying qutip/tests\test_mesolve.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip/tests
copying qutip/tests\test_metrics.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip/tests
copying qutip/tests\test_operators.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip/tests
copying qutip/tests\test_oper_types.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip/tests
copying qutip/tests\test_parallel.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip/tests
copying qutip/tests\test_partial_transpose.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip/tests
copying qutip/tests\test_qft.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip/tests
copying qutip/tests\test_qobj.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip/tests
copying qutip/tests\test_qpt.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip/tests
copying qutip/tests\test_qubitcircuit.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip/tests
copying qutip/tests\test_qubit_evolution.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip/tests
copying qutip/tests\test_rand.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip/tests
copying qutip/tests\test_sparse.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip/tests
copying qutip/tests\test_spinchain.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip/tests
copying qutip/tests\test_sp_eigs.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip/tests
copying qutip/tests\test_states.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip/tests
copying qutip/tests\test_state_types.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip/tests
copying qutip/tests\test_steadystate.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip/tests
copying qutip/tests\test_stochastic_me.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip/tests
copying qutip/tests\test_stochastic_se.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip/tests
copying qutip/tests\test_subsys_apply.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip/tests
copying qutip/tests\test_superoper.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip/tests
copying qutip/tests\test_superop_reps.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip/tests
copying qutip/tests\test_td_formats.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip/tests
copying qutip/tests\test_tensor.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip/tests
copying qutip/tests\test_three_level.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip/tests
copying qutip/tests\test_utilities.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip/tests
copying qutip/tests\test_wigner.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip/tests
copying qutip/tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip/tests
copying qutip\configspec.ini -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip
copying qutip/cy\complex_math.pxi -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip/cy
copying qutip/cy\parameters.pxi -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip/cy
copying qutip/cy\spmatfuncs.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip/cy
copying qutip/cy\graph_utils.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip/cy
copying qutip/cy\sparse_utils.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip/cy
copying qutip/cy\spmatfuncs.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip/cy
copying qutip/cy\stochastic.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip/cy
copying qutip/control\cy_grape.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip/control
copying qutip/tests\bucky.npy -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip/tests
copying qutip/tests\bucky_perm.npy -> build\lib.win32-3.5\qutip/tests
running build_ext
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 159, in <module>
    configuration=configuration
  File "C:\Users\Dhwister\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 169, in setup
    return old_setup(**new_attr)
  File "C:\Users\Dhwister\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Users\Dhwister\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Users\Dhwister\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\Dhwister\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\command\install.py", line 60, in run
    r = old_install.run(self)
  File "C:\Users\Dhwister\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 539, in run
    self.run_command('build')
  File "C:\Users\Dhwister\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Users\Dhwister\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\Dhwister\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\command\build.py", line 47, in run
    old_build.run(self)
  File "C:\Users\Dhwister\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "C:\Users\Dhwister\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Users\Dhwister\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\Dhwister\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 117, in run
    force=self.force)
  File "C:\Users\Dhwister\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\ccompiler.py", line 597, in new_compiler
    compiler = klass(None, dry_run, force)
  File "C:\Users\Dhwister\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\mingw32ccompiler.py", line 96, in __init__
    msvcr_success = build_msvcr_library()
  File "C:\Users\Dhwister\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\mingw32ccompiler.py", line 331, in build_msvcr_library
    if int(msvcr_name.lstrip('msvcr')) < 80:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lstrip'
```

Based on

> [Python error, " 'module' object has no attribute 'lstrip' "](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4690378/python-error-module-object-has-no-attribute-lstrip)

It seems to be string reading for python3.0+, do I need to fix the setup of the package?

Answer (score 0):

Qutip does not install properly on Windows when using PY 3+. This is because the installation looks for visual studio rather than using gcc. You need to use Py 2.7, and if running Anaconda, install the additional mingw and libpython packages.